# SVG Elements added with createElementNS are in the DOM but invisible on screen

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Greetins everybody,

First of all, I'm not an expert in JS, or web dev in general.

My goal is to overlay an image with a SVG, so that when you hover certain parts of it, it highlights.

The problem is as stated in the title: SVG element cretaed via createElementNS() are present in the DOM, but not visible on screen.

Here are the relevant code snippets I created:

```
<span class="image featured" id="tapestry_1_wrapper">
    <svg width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0" id="draw_t1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
    <img src="images/4525_low_800px.jpg" alt="[redacted]" id="t1">
</span>
```

The (truncated) javascript part:

```
svg1 = document.getElementById("draw_t1");
t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
svg1.setAttribute("width", t1.clientWidth);
svg1.setAttribute("height", t1.clientHeight);

var new_rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "my_id");
new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', w);
new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', h);
new_rect.setAttributeNS(null, "style", "stroke: #000000; fill:#FFFF00;");

svg1.appendChild(new_rect);
```

I can see the rectangle in the DOM, if I overlay it in the DOM it highlights it on the SVG, but it never shows otherwise (just a blank space on the page).

If you could give me any pointers to what's wrong, or ways to do it another way, I would be glad.

Cheers!

Comment: the element draw_t1 has viewBox="0 0 0 0" that isn't really a valid canvas.

Comment: Uh, I feel stupid now. Thank you very much!